# How to show the client pop-up when adding a product to the cart?

Tags: magento2

There is a delivery of goods in the store on the day of purchase.
but not all products can be delivered on the day of purchase, so there is a checkbox in the admin when adding goods, this product is available for this delivery or not.
How can I track the moment of pressing the button "add product to the basket" so that I could see a popup that this product is available for delivery today, and if it is not available, it shows that the product is not available is not available for delivery today.

Comment: You can call javascript function on click on add to cart button. Using javascript/jquery you can display popup. You can get checkbox value using product object.

Comment: Yes, but how to implement all this with a module, what methods, maybe someone has just come across something similar.

Comment: This is the for product detail page vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
This is file for product list page vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

You can find add to cart button on both file. Copy this file in your theme and write code for popup on click on button.

Comment: This will not work, because I need to check what product is in the basket, if it has a product that has delivery for the current day, then do not show the popup.
In the second case, if he has goods in a basket where delivery is available on the given day, and he tries to deliver the second product without this delivery, then show popup.